# Compile apache with various modules

Tags: apache, ldap, apache2, solaris

At work we have several Solaris servers.

Each server runs apache which we compiled a few years ago. It's been fine so far.
Now we want to build one apache, using the latest version, and have it include LDAP authentication modules (for AD integration), NTML authentication and mod_perl.

I can't find a guide for building apache like this and distributing it to several servers, rather than recompile on each.

Does anyone know of a good guide, some documents or just have some general hints and tips on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've some guides to compile Apache 1.3.x and 2.2.x on Solaris SPARC in 64bits using SunCC. The post are in Spanish, but you can see how is it.

Here for 2.2.x with Tomcat6

http://sparcki.blogspot.com/2010/04/instalacion-de-apache-httpd-con-tomcat6.html

Also, you can see more options about how to compile Apache HTTPD on Solaris inside the blog, and remember GNU GCC has a "problem" on Solaris when you try to compile in 64bits,

Urko,